# Got a error Project Deployment in Angular 6

Tags: angular, deployment

Got a error while deployment because of Image upload and preview Function.

Function in source code the word of '**result**' mark in red line. But **the function working and image can preiew in template successfully**.

My problem is code working properly but cannot deploy.Please give me a suggestion for change source code or show me my mistake.

**Error in CLI**

```
ERROR in src/app/register/register.component.ts(74,36): error TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

**Error/Warring in Source Code**

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'
```

**Component.ts**

If console 'eventURL' then that array have 'result' element

[image]

```
 onFileChanged(event: any) {
   if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
       this.filesToUpload = event.target.files[0];
       this.filesName = uuid();

       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); 
       reader.onload = (eventURL) => { 
       this.url = eventURL.target.result;
    ;
  }
 }
}
```

**The Image successfully Preview using above function**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the property exists, you could use `event.target['result']` as a workaround. This bypasses typescripts type checking. However I'd make sure that event is cast to the right type to prevent this error from occurring altogether. You could try something like this:

```
let target = event.target as FileReader;
target.result;
```

Comment: it's work for me when I change my code like this `event.target['result']`. Thank you show my mistake.